# Cannot create a new project of any type in VS 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I just installed VS 2010 SP1. After restarting my computer, I installed ASP.NET MVC3 RTM. I again restarted.

Now, I cannot create a new project - of any type in any language. It says "Requested registry access is not allowed.".

Has anybody had the same issue?

Comment: Have you tried starting VS in "Administrator Mode"? What happens then?

Comment: @[Sergi Papaseit] Yes. It didn't make a difference:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press WINDOW+R to open the Run window, type "regedit" (no quotes) and press ENTER to execute. If a UAC dialog appears choose Yes to open the Registry Editor with elevated priveledges.
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.
3. Create a new key named ".vbproj" (.csproj in case of C#)
4. Run VS 2010 as an administrator.
5. Try creating a VB/C# project.

Source: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521505/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed-creating-project-in-vs-2010